# Vim hotkey's corresponding command name

Tags: vim

I'm having trouble finding the command that would match <kbd>%</kbd> in normal mode. Or any command for that matter, i.e. <kbd>yy</kbd> to `:yank`.

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a oneliner like so,
`:s/this/that/g | yank | undo | /* Move down one line */ | /* % */ | paste`

Comment: It might help to give a sample of before/after text. I was a little confused as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do normal mode operations in command mode with normal/norm.

For example, to yank the current line, you'd want `:norm yy`.

Comment: And to make this independent of any mappings, use `:normal!`. This is especially important in plugins, as you don't know what other users have remapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can move to the next `%` character in normal mode with `f%`, and just before it with `t%`